# Porting MD5 from node.js to go

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, go, md5

I have an authentication logic in [node.js](http://nodejs.org/)

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var SaltLength = 9;

function createHash(password) {
  var salt = generateSalt(SaltLength);
  var hash = md5(password + salt);
  return salt + hash;
}

function validateHash(hash, password) {
  var salt = hash.substr(0, SaltLength);
  var validHash = salt + md5(password + salt);
  return hash === validHash;
}

function generateSalt(len) {
  var set = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqurstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQURSTUVWXYZ',
      setLen = set.length,
      salt = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var p = Math.floor(Math.random() * setLen);
    salt += set[p];
  }
  return salt;
}

function md5(string) {
  return crypto.createHash('md5').update(string).digest('hex');
}
```

How can I port it to [Go](http://golang.org)?

Comment: [Did you look at the standard packages ?](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/md5/)

Comment: Please, please don't use MD5 for hashing passwords. Go provides a very nice bcrypt package (http://code.google.com/p/go.crypto/bcrypt) and you can find a solid example here: http://shadynasty.biz/blog/2012/09/05/auth-and-sessions/

Comment: @elithrar There is also good scrypt support. And I agree, MD5 is *not* a *secure* cryptographic hash function anymore.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. Unfortunately I need the exact same algorithm, because I need to integrate the new Go part with the existing node.js service.

Comment: @RafałSobota I hate to carry on about things, but in that case I'd highly recommend pushing the node service to increase security. Salted MD5 provides such a false sense of security that it's arguably not much better than *none* at all. Storing user passwords in MD5 is doing them a huge disservice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only need the standard `md5` algorithm, here's how to use it in go, as noted in the [documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/md5/):

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "crypto/md5"
    "io"
)

func main() {
    h := md5.New()
    io.WriteString(h, "The fog is getting thicker!")
    io.WriteString(h, "And Leon's getting laaarger!")
    fmt.Printf("%x", h.Sum(nil))
}
```

If you need an md5 function that returns a string, here's how to do it:

```
func md5(input string) string {
    h := md5.New()
    io.WriteString(h, input)
    return fmt.Sprintf("%x", h.Sum(nil))
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It was very helpful. Mostly this line `fmt.Printf("%x", h.Sum(nil))`